# ASP.Net Images Not Showing (403: Forbidden)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a list of urls. For example, https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/987560/1.jpg (SFW)

However, when I try to display the images in my View, some of the images **sometimes** load, but the majority do not load.

[image: ExampleImage]

When I paste the urls into my browser, they **all work**.
But when I right-click a broken image and press "Open image in new tab", I receive an `ngix` `403 Forbidden` error.

My View

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Books";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var bookUrl in (List<string>) ViewData["Urls"])
    {
        <img src="@bookUrl"/>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Trying to steal content from other websites? tsk tsk...

Comment: nhentai has a public API. And this is for my own learning of C# and ASP.

Comment: Do the API expose the image links? If yes then they will state somewhere the restrictions they impose, you are being forbidden by some limit, maybe simultaoneous requests, hits per second or whatever. But I doubt they give you the access to the images directly, that's why they restricted it, to avoid people like you.

Comment: Most likely, the server has some checks in place to prevent hot linking

Comment: Oh I see, I did not even consider being rate limited and blocked by similar checks. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with this specific site host.
Try to link another image from different url and it should work.